# Page won't scroll on Iphone chrome or Safari but will on Android and PC

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on the following page and I can not figure out why I can not scroll the page when used on my physical iphone 5s

http://chatface.me/

If you go to the page above, you will be presented with a form that contains three text boxes, username, password and email address. After those get filled out, another page will load inside the iframe, it's this page that should be able to scroll. I can scroll it when on PC or Android, but not when using my IPhone 5s. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: try to add CSS3 property [ -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch; overflow:auto;] to the parent container

Comment: I have inspected your code. You have used attribute 'scrolling="no"' for your iframe. Just remove that attribute,it will solve your problem

Comment: @GSB that would be a different scroll though. That would create a second scroll box around the iframe if I would be on Android or PC

Comment: Try adding overflow attribute in your iframe's css `<iframe id="frame" style="margin:0px 0px 20px 0px; width: 100%; height: 1100px;overflow-y:scroll " src="http://www.dateverifytracking.com/cpa.php?mt=426629&amp;ofid=110&amp;tid=1" frameborder="0"></iframe>`